# trying to create ul element then create li children element with the ul parent using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JavaScript so I am trying to learn the concepts first, that's why I am gonna attach two code samples, and I want to know why the second sample doesn't work.

**The issue is:**
when I am trying to append the **li** element using **sample 2** it doesn't work, but why?

sample 1

```
<body>
    <h1>This is my List </h1>
    <button onclick="j()">click me</button>
    <script>
        function j()
        {
            var ul = document.createElement('ul');
            ul.innerHTML = 'List:'
            document.body.appendChild(ul);

            let u = document.createElement('li');
            u.innerHTML = 'person';
            ul.appendChild(u);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

sample 2

```
<body>
    <h1>This is my List </h1>
    <button onclick="j()">click me</button>
    <script>
        function j()
        {
            var ul = document.createElement('ul');
            ul.innerHTML = 'List:'
            document.body.appendChild(ul);

            let u = document.createElement('li');
            u.innerHTML = 'person';
            document.getElementsByTagName("ul").appendChild(u);  //ul here is the one created within the function.
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: two minor thoughts on your code since you are starting your journey:
1. use `let` instead of `var` ... always :)
2. elemen.innerHTML can do things you may not want - have a look at `document.createTextNode()` as well

Comment: you're right, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[`document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) returns a collection.

So your code should be `document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].appendChild(u)` assuming you only have this one `<ul>` in your document.

You can use `document.querySelector("ul")` instead to find a specific element.

---

Side note: `ul.innerHTML = 'List:'` is invalid HTML, `<ul>`'s HTML should only contain `<li>` elements.

You can do `ul.innerHTML = '<li>List:</li>'` or you should consider using another element like `<h1>` to hold the title.